# Fatal error running local project with xampp

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I got the errors below while working on my project:

> Warning: require(C:\app-isw\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\app-isw\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

and

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\app-isw\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\app-isw\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

How can I resolve them?

I've update composer but the problem persist.

Comment: Check your paths and compare that to your document-tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you maybe forgot to *install* the project dependencies? Run `composer install` in `C:\app-isw` I would say.

Comment: no i just have 5.2 laravel then copy my app folder and models and migrations and views and public folder into 7.2 laravel and after edit serviceproviders php artisan serve run and this error appeared